# Update region_name with the latest sale_date in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a transactions data with this kind of data

| customer_id | region_name | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10/2/2011 |
| 1 | D | 8/2/1011 |
| 1 | D | 19/2/2011 |
| 2 | B | 5/5/1011 |
| 2 | C | 15/7/2011 |
| 2 | B | 10/5/1011 |

I want the region_name to be update with the region where the latest transaction was made. so the resultant table should be like:

| customer_id | region_name | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | 10/2/2011 |
| 1 | D | 8/2/1011 |
| 1 | D | 19/2/2011 |
| 2 | C | 5/5/1011 |
| 2 | C | 15/7/2011 |
| 2 | C | 10/5/1011 |

Any help will be highly appreciated

Tried this but I can't use UPDATE which will udate the original dataset

```
UPDATE transactions t
JOIN (
  SELECT customer_id, MAX(sale_date) AS latest_sale_date
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY customer_id
) latest_sales
ON t.customer_id = latest_sales.customer_id AND t.sale_date = latest_sales.latest_sale_date
SET t.region_name = (
  SELECT region_name
  FROM transactions
  WHERE customer_id = t.customer_id AND sale_date = latest_sales.latest_sale_date
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below *UPDATE* query.

```sql
UPDATE transactions t
   SET t.region_name = u.region_name
  FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, 
           ANY_VALUE(region_name HAVING MAX PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', sale_date)) region_name 
      FROM transactions GROUP BY 1
  ) u
 WHERE t.customer_id = u.customer_id;

-- Query results
SELECT * FROM transactions;
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| customer_id | region_name | sale_date |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|           1 | D           | 10/2/2011 |
|           1 | D           | 19/2/2011 |
|           1 | D           | 8/2/1011  |
|           2 | C           | 10/5/1011 |
|           2 | C           | 5/5/1011  |
|           2 | C           | 15/7/2011 |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**See also**

- [HAVING MAX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate-function-calls#max_min_clause)